How to handle errors caused by non-JAX objects (such as scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) in JAX custom_vjp?
I am using JAX to implement custom backpropagation (custom_vjp), but in my function, one of the input parameters is a sparse matrix of type scipy.sparse.csr_matrix. Since JAX expects all parameters to support JAX numerical operations (i.e. have a dtype attribute), my code will report an error during forward propagation, saying that JAX cannot handle scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.
Here is my simplified code:
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import scipy.sparse as sp
from jax import custom_vjp

@custom_vjp
def simple_function_vjp(sparse_matrix, vector):
    return sparse_matrix @ vector

def simple_function_fwd(sparse_matrix, vector):
    return simple_function_vjp(sparse_matrix, vector), (sparse_matrix, vector)

def simple_function_bwd(residuals, grad_output):
    sparse_matrix, vector = residuals
    # Backpropagation: Computing the gradient of the input
    grad_vector = sparse_matrix.T @ grad_output
    grad_sparse_matrix = jnp.outer(grad_output, vector)
    
    # The first is the gradient of the sparse matrix, the second is the gradient of the vector
    return (grad_sparse_matrix, grad_vector)

simple_function_vjp.defvjp(simple_function_fwd, simple_function_bwd)

def simple_test():
    sparse_matrix = sp.csr_matrix([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
    vector = jnp.array([2.0, 3.0])

    output_value = simple_function_vjp(sparse_matrix, vector)
    grad_value = jax.grad(output_value)

    print("Forward propagation results:", output_value)
    print("Gradient results:", grad_value)

simple_test()

I have tried converting the sparse matrix to jax.numpy or numpy's sparse matrix format, but this can result in excessive memory overhead, especially if the matrix is ​​very large. Ideally, I would like to be able to continue to use the sparse representation of scipy.sparse.csr_matrix and customize the gradient calculations in JAX.
My question is how to handle non-JAX objects like scipy.sparse.csr_matrix in custom_vjp? And is there some efficient way to handle forward and backward propagation of sparse matrices without converting them to dense matrices?

scipy.sparse classes cannot readily be used by other libraries or packages.  As you found converting to numpy arrays  (.toarray()) can make things understandable, but easily runs into memory errors.  Some scikit packages explicitly say they can handle sparse matrices.

JAX transformations like grad are not compatible with scipy.sparse objects and operations; they are only compatible with JAX arrays and operations.
You might be able to make progress here by creating a JAX-compatible data structure to represent your CSR object (see Extending Pytrees), and then for the scipy operation you could use jax.pure_callback to execute the scipy operation from JAX (see Example: pure callback with custom_jvp).
I still think you'll probably run into issues, because your backward rule returns a dense gradient for the sparse input, so the array shapes won't match: autodiff with respect to sparse matrices is somewhat tricky.
If you want an implementation of CSR matrices in JAX where all of the above concerns are already handled for you, you could use the BCSR type from jax.experimental.sparse. For example:
import jax
import scipy.sparse as sp
import jax.experimental.sparse as jsp

sparse_matrix = sp.csr_matrix([[2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 3.0]])

spmat_jax = jsp.BCSR.from_scipy_sparse(sparse_matrix)
vector = jnp.array([2.0, 3.0])

def f(vector):
  return spmat_jax @ vector

print(f(vector))
# [4. 9.]

# Use jacobian, because grad only applies for scalar-valued functions.
print(jax.jacobian(f)(vector))
# [[2. 0.]
#  [0. 3.]]

